# Possible to set color based on attribute while using 2.5D symbology?

Tags: qgis, symbology, rule-based, 3d-map, qgis2threejs

I'm using 2.5D symbology to have my features display at different heights based on a certain attribute, but would also like the features displayed as different colors based on another attribute.

Is this possible without creating a 3d map view (in qgis3) or using the Qgis2Threejs plugin?

I'm using Qgis 3.4 but also have Qgis 2.18.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution by accident, and it may not be intentionally a feature but I've reproduced the results following the same steps twice.

1) Set the layer symbology based on height using the 2.5D option. your layer will be 3d but in one color. Click apply.

2) Change the symbology to whatever color-based type you want (in my case graduated w/spectral color scheme) based on the attribute column of your choosing. Click apply.

3) That's it.

The changes persisted after saving, closing Qgis and reopening.

Comment: FYI, that's by design and documented https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#d-renderer ;)

Comment: Ah, good to know.